# running sanitize_sql_array outside of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm writing a script to build some sql queries and I want to sanitize the query before I execute it. When i call sanitize_sql_array on the array I hit an exception, 'undefined method 'sanitize_sql_array''. How do utilize that active record function without calling from within a model?

Comment: If you really want to, you can call the protected class method like this: `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, your_array)` ( you can also use any of models instead of ActiveRecord::Base)