# Making ActiveRecord sanitization methods available in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am building a filter class that constructs special sql queries. It's a service class, not a model and has no underlying table.

I want to sanitize the input when embedding it into the sql, to safeguard against injection.

These methods do exactly what I want: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html

However, using `include ActiveRecord::Sanitization` does not work. When I call `sanitize_sql_array` it complains:

```
Undefined local variable or method `connection` Applications::ApplicationFilter:Class
```

Which is seemingly some kind of dependency issue. When I inherit my filter class from AR, with `Applications::ApplicationFilter < ActiveRecord::Base`, then it works. But I don't want to do that.. please.. please please please

Does anyone know how to make this `sanitize_sql_array` method available without inheriting from the whole big lumpy activerecord rhinoserous?

Answer (score 4):

[running sanitize_sql_array outside of a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808148/running-sanitize-sql-array-outside-of-a-model)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ['test < ?', 123])
```